# How to verify JavaScript code is valid in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I need to take some non-trivial javascript and ensure that all code paths have code that is valid.  For example:

```
var num = 1;
if (num == 2) {
    badFunctionName();
}
```

and I need to do this from C#.  On top of validating it, I need to produce nice error messages explaining line number and column number of bad code.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

UPDATE - Corrected the confusion by saying javascript syntax.  My intent is to ensure that all execution paths have valid javascript code (probably as defined by jslint).

Comment: The code sample you show doesn't have any syntax errors. (An `if` condition that is never true and an undefined function are not syntax errors.)

Comment: @nnnnnn JsLint reports it as "Undeclared 'badFunctionName'.".  I would like to report the same error back.  That being said, I don't know if JsLint is the best way to do this and if so, how to I lint this code via c#? BTW, I only wrote the code as a sample to show that I want to test code that is not in the execution path.

Comment: Can't you simply run jslint on the code and report back the output?

Answer (score 1):

Use [eslint](http://eslint.org) to validate your Javascript.  Rules are configurable and pluggable.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you would need to leverage something like [Javascript.NET](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net) or [jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) for compiling the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can download **Microsoft.JScript** dll from [here](http://www.dlldownloader.com/microsoft-jscript-dll/)

Set reference to the dll file in your project, and use it like this:

```
var compiler = new JScriptCodeProvider().CreateCompiler();
var res = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(), @"C:\path_to_your_js_file.js");
```

Works for me...

Answer (score -1):

You could add a reference to Microsoft.JScript and check for errors like that:

```
using (var compiler = new JavaScriptCompiler ()) {
    compiler.Compile(javascriptFiles);
    if (compiler.HasErrors)
        /* Do something with the error message */
        throw new Exception (string.Format ("Error: {0}", compiler.ErrorMessage));
}
```